# Cookie (string? name, string value, string path, string domain)

Tags: java, vb.net

Hola buenos días a todos, estoy haciendo un proyecto para comunicarme con una url que solicita una cookie para su comunicacion,para lo cual estoy utilizando la clase cookie

```
    Cookie (string? name, string value, string path, string domain)
```

La cookie que se requiere para comunicarme con la url es Cookie: mac=00:1A:79:34:A2:FC; stb_lang=en; timezone=Europe%2FParis;, aplicando la clase cookie, me queda así:

```
    req.Cookies.Set("mac", 00:1A:79:34:A2:FC, bluemedmedia.ddns.net, "/")
    req.Cookies.Set("stb_lang", "en", bluemedmedia.ddns.net, "/")
    req.Cookies.Set("timezone", "Europe%2FParis", bluemedmedia.ddns.net, "/")
```

pero no eh logrado comunicarme ya que la cookie no se genera, estoy utilizando la librería Leaf.xNet, alguien podrá ayudarme o decirme en donde estoy fallando de favor.

Comment: Seguro que esta pregunta es en `c++`, `vb.net` y `java`? No sera solo uno de los lenguajes?

Comment: Pablochaches, es solo para vb.net mil disculpa, tu podrás apoyarme o recomendarme a alguien para que me ayude

Comment: sorry bro, en este campo si no se nada. A lo mucho te puedo recomendar el articulo de [como hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No digo que la tuya sea mala, ya que no se del tema, pero para que cuando alguien que si sepa del tema llegue, si sepa bien que es lo que necesitas. Mucha suerte.